# How to send JSON RPC to web service and get response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I want to send JSON RPC with method and parameters in my iOS application. I am using [https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking][1] github library but I could not find anyway to get returned response back.

My JSON RPC call is 
UrlString: [http://stokercloud.dk/registeration/jsonapi/api.php][1]

Remote function: check2Serial2($secretkey,$serial,$userid)

This is my JSON request, where as parameters are

```
 NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"secretkey": @"serial", @"userid": @[@abcde123, @901400001, @12345678]};
 [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"check2Serial" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In below line

`[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"check2Serial" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters error:nil];`

You should use `POST` instead of `check2Serial` i think. it should be post or get or put etc but not `check2Serial`. Second thing you should `sessiondatatask` to send it to server.

hope this will help :)

Comment: No, it is remote web method, that must be called. Here is link for JSON-RPC wrapper that I used. https://github.com/dbowen/Demiurgic-JSON-RPC. There was also RPC Wrapper available for AFNetworking but that was outdated now.